# Add View - Cannot retrieve Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am still new to MVC, but I am starting to get a feel for the general picture however I still mixup things like `namespace`, or `using` and I THINK that may be the case here where I am mis-referencing something.

**Question:** I am trying to add an `EmployeeInfo` View, with a `List` template, with Model class: `EmployeeInfo`, with data context class: `MoviesEntities`

The auto-generation will not execute. When I right-click in Controller's method EmployeeInfo. I select the option "Add View", fill in the information, then hit add and during the scaffolding load screen it gives me the error as follows.

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to
>   retrieve metadata for 'WebApplication2.Models.EmployeeInfo'.'

My controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Entities;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities();

        // GET: /Movies/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult EmployeeInfo()
        {  
            var query =
            from m in db.Movies
            join me in db.MovieEmployees 
            on m.ID equals me.movieID
            join e in db.Employees
            on me.employeeID equals e.ID
            join r in db.Roles
            on me.roleID equals r.ID

            select new EmployeeInfo() {Name = e.Name, Role = r.RoleType, Birthday = e.Birthday };

            return View(query.Distinct().ToList());
          }
    }
}
```

My context

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated> Built from database Movie </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebApplication2.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using movieLayer;
    using WebApplication2.Models;

    public partial class MoviesEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MoviesEntities()
            : base("name=MoviesEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MovieEmployee> MovieEmployees { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Show> Shows { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication2.Models.EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfoes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model of `EmployeeInfo`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApplication2.Models


{
    public class EmployeeInfo
    {

        public EmployeeInfo() { }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to make a View for EmployeeInfo

Comment: On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: @tereško It won't run the auto-generation when I right-click in Controller's method EmployeeInfo. I select the options, hit add, and during the scaffolding load screen it gives me the error

Comment: @Andrei No line. It is after I submit the "Add View" option for EmployeeInfo, it stops and spits out the error.

Comment: Is EmployeeInfo an entity or just a model object you have created?

Comment: @DavidG I believe it is just a model object (I am only using it for the View). Since I am querying a selection of multiple items, I had to make a model otherwise the query becomes type Anonymous. So I was told to make a Model for the View then generate my View off of that.

Comment: @Austin then why is it part of your context if it's not meant to be an entity?

Comment: Wait, maybe I mis-used my terms ( I am new to this afterall). I have a context that was built from a database connection called Movies. I have a Moviescontroller with the method (EmployeeInfo) as seen above. I was told that in order to show a View with multiple columns being selected that I need a model to pass that information too, otherwise it makes them all Anonymous. I made the model above called EmployeeInfo and now I am trying to just right-click the EmployeeInfo method in the controller, and use the option "Add View" to auto-generate my view with the variables in the model. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `EmployeeInformation` was just a "template" for the controller to dump it's data into from the query for the View.

`EmployeeInformation` was not actually an existing table, thus I had to make a model i.e. `EmpleeInfoModels` to hold the data, that was then passed to my custom View.

Method

```
public ActionResult EmployeeInformation()
        {
            var query =
            from m in db.Movies

            join me in db.MovieEmployees
            on m.ID equals me.movieID

            join e in db.Employees
            on me.employeeID equals e.ID

            join r in db.Roles
            on me.roleID equals r.ID

            select new EmployeeInfoModels() { Name = e.Name, RoleType = r.RoleType, Birthdate = e.Birthday, eID = e.ID };

            return View(query.Distinct().ToList().Distinct());
        }
```

Model

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class EmployeeInfoModels
    {
        public int mID { get; set; }
        public int eID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string RoleType { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my View just brought in

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.EmployeeInfoModels>
```

Answer (score 5):

What I did to solve this issue that I encountered when adding a scaffolded view by right clicking the controller action was to leave the "Data context class" field blank.

[image]

I'm not entirely sure as to why this works but I found this method from [ASP.NET forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2051386.aspx?Error%20when%20adding%20View%20Unable%20to%20retrieve%20metadata%20for%20efEntity%20Could%20not%20find%20the%20CLR%20type%20for%20Model%20).

Comment: @Toolkit not in all cases. If you downvoted my answer I would like to know the reason since the answer may work for other people. Regardless, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: In my case this was happening when creating a view for a ViewModel and in that case there was no need to specify the Data Context  Class.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you rebuild your solution first. If you just added a new class, the scaffolding engine may not actually know about it, yet, if the project hasn't compiled.

If that doesn't work, close Visual Studio and restart. I have seen the scaffolding stuff just go wonky for no good reason in VS2012, and a restart will usually fix it.

Comment: I tried restarting but it did not work. Also, I also cannot seem to locate the Rebuild option. On our visual studios 2012 it doesn't have MVC 5, so I am using Web Express 2013 for this practice project.

Comment: FWIW, you can use MVC 5 in VS2012, you just have to install the updated web tooling: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532. As for 2013, the Build menu is still there in the same spot it's always been, so I'm not sure what is confusing you there.

Comment: Oh I can build, just not rebuild haha. Either way, the issue persists :(

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more tip: you may have this error if you have any configSource attributes in any of the elements in your web.config. I commented out all of the elements that contained a configSource attribute and then ran the scaffolding again and it worked like a charm. Once it was finished, I uncommented the elements in the web.config and I was all set.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `DataContextClass` Option in Add View Pop winow and then correct the `ConnectionString` when adding your View from Controller

[Refer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52gM3.png)
.